# Apple store - react native binary refused

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, app-store, testflight

I'm currently facing an issue trying to publish an update of my app in the Apple store.

When the app tries to connect to the API, the loader spins indefinitely.

[image: loader spins indefinitely]

When I test my app in all conditions it works perfectly.

I tried my app :

- with different IOS version (including the 14.1 of IOS),
- in debug mode,
- in release mode,
- with the testFlight app on an Iphone device
- I also tried the connection with a VPN to check the server connection from another location

Moreover, I didn't change anything in my code that could alter the connection between the app and the server.
The app also works perfectly on Android.

Comment: Have you tested on a pure IPv6 network?

Comment: @Paulw11 Interesting that it might be IP related. Would you be willing to elaborate on that?

Comment: Apple tests on a pure IPv6 network.  You need to ensure that your app works correctly on a pure IPv6 network. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for your comment. I tried to follow the guide and create an NT64 Internet Sharing (as describe in the tutorial). I was able to connect my iphone throw the wi-fi and reproduce the issue. However, all apps in the iphone cannot work and i do not have internet access. That's a little bit confusing. Even if the error is in my app, others app should work correctly ? I also tested my api with the following website ( https://ipv6-test.com/validate.php ) to check if the server is "ipv6 ready" and it is .. May be you have an idea ?

Comment: If nothing is working on the IPv6 network then you probably have an issue with how you set up the test network. Regardless, you have identified a problem with your app launching when it cannot contact a server.  You should fix this; at least provide an error message after a timeout. You will still need to work out why Apple is unable to contact your server before they  will be able to review your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved making appeal of the reviewer's decision ... The app was totaly ok ...

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue too. I tested my app all the way like you said. Also test with NT64 Internet Sharing too and i haven't get any issue like Apple said. They can't connect our api.